# How to filter out cells that contain specific words?

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

Is there a way to use the "Filter" feature to filter out cells that contain the words "_design" and "_obdm"?

[image]

So that the cells that are left will be:

[image]

Comment: Are looking for formula or Excel filtering method?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the filter to text filter, then select "text does not contain" and type "design" and "obdm"

[image]

after activating the filter you will get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can wish to do it by formula then could try-

```
=FILTER(A2:A10,BYROW(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Design","obdm"},A2:A10)),LAMBDA(x,NOT(OR(x)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Filter Column of Data (`REDUCE`)

- It will allow a single criterion or an array (range) of criteria (`REDUCE` doesn't care.).

```
=LET(Data,A2:A9,Criteria,{"_design";"_obdm"},
    Ones,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Data),,,0),
    cData,REDUCE(Ones,Criteria,
        LAMBDA(Seq,Crit,Seq*ISERROR(SEARCH(Crit,Data)))),
FILTER(Data,cData))
```

[image]